# Issues in using new Toolbar component,hiding and showing Navigation drawer icon ,Home Up icon click event from fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, android-navigation, android-toolbar

I recently started updating my app to use the new Toolbar component introduced in Android 5.0 with navigation drawer. Flow of app is : MainActivity which has a toolbar, navigation drawer with menu 1. Home  2. Cart.

Home Menu navigates to "Home Detail" through a button in it.

Layout of "MainActivity" :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<include
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    layout="@layout/toolbar" />
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/activity_frame" 
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I am adding two fragments HomeFragment,CartFragment on "MainActivity" on menu selected from drawer as below, default selection is position 0 i.e "Home"

class "MainActivity.java" ::

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();     
    drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    tvTitle = (TextView) mToolbar.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
    if (mToolbar != null) {
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);          
    }       
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer,mToolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
        }
    };
    drawer.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);        
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);    
    dataList = new ArrayList<DrawerItem>();
    dataList.add(new DrawerItem(Constants.V_HOME, R.drawable.ic_launcher));
    dataList.add(new DrawerItem(Constants.V_MY_CART, R.drawable.ic_launcher));  
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapterDrawer);      
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());      
    // to show first "Home fragment" on start up of application
    if(savedInstanceState==null)
        SelectItem(0);
}
public void SelectItem(int position) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        fragment = new HomeFragment();
        replaceFragment(fragment, Constants.V_TAG_HOME,false,"Home");
        break;
    case 1:
        fragment = new CartFragment();
        replaceFragment(fragment, Constants.V_TAG_MY_CART,false,"My Cart");
        break;
    }           
    drawer.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
}
public void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment,String fragment_tag,boolean showHome,String title){   
    frgManager = this.getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft  = frgManager.beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.activity_frame,fragment,fragment_tag);      
    if(showHome)
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.commit();            
    shouldDisplayHomeUp(showHome);
}
public void shouldDisplayHomeUp(boolean showHome){
    if(showHome){
        mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
        drawer.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);   
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }else{
        mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
        drawer.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    }
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {         
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
      return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {   
    switch (item.getItemId()) 
       {        
          case android.R.id.home:            
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"main act  clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();      
             return false;        
          default:            
             return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);    
       }
}
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    if(frgManager.getBackStackEntryCount()>0){      
           getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();      
           // show the drawer icon when on moving back 
           shouldDisplayHomeUp(false);         
        }else{
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}
```

My home fragment has button "Detail" on click of button,replaces to other fragment :"HomeDetailFragment"

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnDetail"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Home detail" />
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/home_frame_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

class "HomeFragment.java" btnDetail click event which replace to other fragment "HomeDetailFragment"::

```
btnDetail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {           
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Fragment fragment = new HomeDetailFragment();
            ((MainActivity)getActivity()).showDrawerIndicator(false);
            FragmentManager frManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft  = frManager.beginTransaction();
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
            ft.replace(R.id.activity_frame, fragment).commit();
        }
});
```

class "HomeDetailFragment.java" ::

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);    
    // update the actionbar to show the up carat/affordance 
    ((MainActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {       
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:    
            // your code for order here
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "home detail", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
        ((MainActivity)getActivity()).onBackPressed();          
     return true;
    }
    return true;
}
```

**My problems ::**

**1. In "HomeDetailFragment", I can see the "UP home icon" but cannot get the click event of home icon `onOptionsItemSelected` not being called, so cant navigate back to HomeFragment**

**2. When pressing the Phone Back Button, and again navigating to "Home Detail" it is not showing "UP home icon"**

Please guide me.

Comment: I have the same issue. But I can't see the back button in my detail fragment. When I try to use getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true) app getting NullpoiterException. Can you please post your style?

Answer (score 3):

> 1. In "HomeDetailFragment", I can see the "UP home icon" but cannot get the click event of home icon onOptionsItemSelected not being called, so cant navigate back to HomeFragment

One way to achieve this is by using the `Toolbar` from your `MainActivity` like so:

```
Toolbar mToolbar= ((MainActivity)getActivity()).mToolbar;
mToolbar.setNavigationIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_nav_back));
mToolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("MrE", "home selected");
            }
        });
```

---

> 2. When pressing the Phone Back Button, and again navigating to "Home Detail" it is not showing "UP home icon"

The reason your code isn't getting called is because it is in the `onCreate` of your Fragment. Move it to the `onCreateOptionsMenu` instead to have it update.

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    // Put toolbar stuff from above here
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

Comment: thnk you for ur response. I am having some doubts in your solution. When I am trying to get Click event of toolbar through `setNavigationOnClickListener` it is also firing on drawer icon click,not only on home back button. How should I deal with this.

Comment: @Dory in the clicklistener, you can check whether mDrawerToggle has drawerIndicator enabled or not and then from that, you can determine the what to do. Something along the line:
   if (mDrawerToggle.isDrawerIndicatorEnabled()) {
         //drawer selected
   } else {
         //home selected
   }
Hope this helps!

Comment: @MrEnginner13 In a similar scenario, how to get navigation drawer icon to work? I have used `Toolbar` and `fragments` with navigation drawer.

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact issue.

Use the **setToolbarNavigationClickListener** method.

In MainActivity.java,

```
actionBarToggle.setToolbarNavigationClickListener(new View.OnClickListener({
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            MainActivity.this.onSupportNavigateUp();
        }
    });
```

Avoid implementing Up Navigation individually in Fragments.

Answer (score 0):

1. You called `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)` which shows the button in the toolbar but doesn't activate it.
   Calling `getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);` in addition should do the job.
2. You show the back-button in the toolbar from within the Fragment which is something I would avoid. Try moving this part to your Activity, when you do the FragmentTransaction.

Comment: I didnot understood your second point u mentioned. Could you please elaborate me more,what should i change.

Comment: In the `onCreate` of your Fragment you call the `setDisplayHomeUpAsEnabled()`. I'd rather do that in the `SelectItem` of your Activity.

Comment: I have used `getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);` still i cannot get click event of home button. I doesnot call even `onOptionsItemSelected`

Comment: Could you add the `onCreate` of your Activity to your question?

Comment: Updated `MainActivity.java`

Comment: Have you tried putting `getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);` and `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)` into the `SelectItem` method?

Comment: In `SelectItem` method while replacing fragment in `replaceFragment` method you can observe I have called `shouldDisplayHomeUp` method which handles calling of both methods.

Comment: I just saw `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` is called in your Fragment. This could cause that the Activity won't handle the click but the Fragment. Can you catch the event by overriding the `onOptionsItemSelected()` in your Fragment?

Comment: I have override `onOptionsItemSelected()` in "HomeDetailFragment.java" which is never been called. And it doesnot call `onOptionsItemSelected()` of activity also.

Comment: I'm in your same situation. I need exactly what you need. I hope it's not a Toolbar problem or something in the support 21